# Command line in Win 7: What did I change accidentially because some skripts are not working any more

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I'm using several scripts (mostly from type bat) on a windows 7 64 bit system. Today I found the following strange behaviour:

```
"C:\Perl64\bin\perl.exe" index_html\mkindex.pl temp\filter.xml temp 25
```

is resulting in an error "access refused" (my bad translation from German "Zugriff verweigert"). Sometimes you will receive:

```
C:\Perl64\bin\perl.exe is not a valid Win32-Anwendung (".. ist keine zulässige Win32-Anwendung")
```

The point is that this command works yesterday fine (in fact the command was recalled in the open command line windows (shell) from the execution from yesterday).

Digging a little more in to the system I discovered:

- The command line has on the title bar C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe
- Other previously working shell scripts are producing now the same error.
- Also a reboot does not change anything.

Could anybody explain this?

Comment: Maybe you could try [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to log all actions, that perl.exe tries and check where an "Access Denied" happens. Or you strip down your perl script to find the exact call that leads to your error.

Comment: As your solution was nothing to do with programming I recommend you delete your question and answer.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:
The perl.exe has a size of 0 bytes. Digging more into this the system department changed virus scanner settings and this put perl.exe into quarantine.

I have to discuss with them why I was not informed.

Comment: Hopefully that helps other persons to understand this misleading message from windows: A zero byte application could be either compatible nor incompatible. And be aware from surprises from system department...